# Using Custom Scale function for ReCharts or d3-scale

Tags: d3.js, scale, recharts

I want to display Weibull analysis plot using Recharts. For Weibull analysis, formula for Y-Axis Scale is as:

***ln(-ln(1-p))***

where p=(i-0.3)/(n+0.4) and i is the rank of the observation. This scale is chosen in order to linearize the resulting plot for Weibull data. You can have a look at the Y Axis log scale as shown in the example graph below.

I tried standard ***scaleLog()*** but I need to customize the log function.

`const y_scale = scaleLog().range([0, 100]);`

Also, one of the recharts issue shows an option of function while defining scale, but that also does not seem to work.

https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/305

Would be great if someone could help with the way to implement custom scale functions.

Example of Weibull Graph: 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recharts seems to have added exactly what you were searching on the documentation of `YAxis`

https://recharts.org/en-US/api/YAxis#scale

```
import { scaleLog } from 'd3-scale';
const scale = scaleLog().base(Math.E);

...
  <YAxis scale={scale} />
...
```